# Regexp_replace PART of unicode (emoji) in Scala-Spark dataframe

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, unicode, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use spark `regexp_replace` to replace all emojis whose unicode **starts** with
`\uD83D` and replace *just that part* of the unicode with  `\uD83D`, but I've had no luck.

Here is an example:

I want to take all instances of "" (which in Scala is `\uD83D\uDE02`) and replace those with " ". That's easy enough with one emoji and works with this code:

```
.select(functions.regexp_replace($"text2", "[(\uD83D\uDE02)]", " \uD83D\uDE02").as("split2"))
```

With the above code, if I have a string like this "" in the text2 column, it will turn it into "    ", which I can then easily split by space.

I want to apply this to ALL emojis that start with `\uD83D` so I would assume doing this should work, but it doesn't:

```
.select(functions.regexp_replace($"text2", "[(\uD83D)]", " \uD83D").as("split2"))
```

This does not affect the data in any way. Even the following does not affect the data in any way, with or without the parenthesis and/or brackets:

```
.select(functions.regexp_replace($"text2", "[(u)]", " \uD83D").as("split2"))
```

If I could replace just the first 6 characters of those unicode strings, the following in the text2 column: "" would result in "    ", which is exactly what I need.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you want to 1) check each grapheme and 2) if it is an emoji that starts with `\uD83D`, enclose with spaces? Then in Scala, it would look like `"""\P{M}\p{M}*+""".r.replaceAllIn(YOUR_STRING_HERE, m => if (m.group(0).startsWith("\uD83D")) s" ${m.group(0)} " else m.group(0) )`. Not sure how to do that in spark though, the `regexp_replace` does not seem to support a lambda as a replacement argument. The problem is detecting the start of an emoji.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `\\B\uD83D.{1}` and replace with the captured group `$1` and space. Then trim to get rid of the last space and split:

```
val df = Seq(
  (""),
  ("")
).toDF("text2")

df.select(
  split(
    trim(regexp_replace($"text2", "(\\B\uD83D.{1})", "$1 ")),
    " "
  ).as("split2")
).show

//+-----------------+
//|          split2 |
//+-----------------+
//|[, , , ]|
//|[, , , ]|
//+-----------------+
```